# Unlocking oem Elephone p9000

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, twrp, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to flash TWRP on my elephone P9000, but when I use SP flash tools it doesn't download anything to my device,

so I decided to try adb. To get access to write a new recovery, I need to unlock bootloader/OEM. When I enter the command `fastboot oem unlock` my phone asks if I'm sure I want to, and I have to press the volume up button to confirm. The problem: when I do that, nothing happens. I can go back if I use the volume down button. The volume buttons normally work just fine.

I tried all the tutorials I could find about how to install TWRP. Anyone any idea?